# How to avoid using too much foreign key django

Tags: django

I just want to store tags data inside entry model

Entry

- title
- content
- tags

Tags should be Array but ArrayField is not portable to other database. I want to use portable alternative.

Comment: Your best bet is to use a many to many relation in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The portable alternative is to use a proper relational schema - in this case a many to many relationship, which in django models is named [`models.ManyToManyField`.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(...)



class Entry(models.Model):
    # ...
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

If you want to keep tags ordering per entry, you'll need an intermediate model to store it, cf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany

Comment: We meet again! an answer I can agree with +1